# How to save file object to a field after using"file_scan_directory"

Tags: drupal-7

I try to use file_scan_directory to scan some files and get some local path, and I want them to become an object and save into db, so I need file_save to do so.
file_save take an file object as parameter, and how can I suppose to success this procedure?

I have try file_save_upload, API doc mentioned the parameter "$source --- A string specifying the filepath or URI of the uploaded file to save.", however it seems not to read the path and always return null.

I also try to custom create a file object for file_save to run, it does work but don't think it's in correct drupal way, would there be any solution for:

file_scan_directory-> ???? -> file_save -> field_attach_update (* update a field with new fid once the file is save)

please help for this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will scan some jpg files, save into db, and attach the files to a field.

```
function test_form(){
  $node = node_load('61');
  unset($node->field_image[$node->language]);

  $files = file_scan_directory('public://testimport', '/^.*\.(jpg|JPG)$/');

  //dpm($files);

  //http://drupal.org/node/889058
  foreach($files as $fileobj){

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $result = $query
      ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'file')
      ->propertyCondition('uri', $fileobj->uri)
      //$query->propertyCondition('uri', 'public://%', 'LIKE');
      ->execute();

    if(isset($result['file'])){
      dpm($result['file']);
      $fid = reset($result['file'])->fid;
      $fileobj = file_load($fid);
    }else{
      $fileobj->filemine = file_get_mimetype($fileobj->uri);
      $fileobj = file_save($fileobj);
    }

    $node->field_image[$node->language][] = array(
      'fid' => $fileobj->fid,
      //'alt' => $node->title,
      //'title' => $node->title,
      'uid' => '1',
      'filename' => $fileobj->filename,
      'uri' => $fileobj->uri,
      'filemime' => $fileobj->filemime,
      'filesize'=> $fileobj->filesize,
      'status' => '1',
    );

  }

  if($node = node_submit($node)) { // Prepare node for saving
    node_save($node);
    echo "Node with nid " . $node->nid . " updated!\n";
  }
}
```